# Tailwind CSS classes on some components don't work

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a project created with NextJS and ReactJS. I've installed Tailwind CSS and used in some components which are located in 'components' folder.

I created one more component in same 'components' folder, named 'Thumbnail.js'. I wanted to use `h-2 truncate p-2` in a p tag inside of 'Thumbnail'. They didn't show any effect on the components. And can't even see these class names in Chrome debugger.

In the same 'Thumbnail' component I've used `transform hover:scale` and interestingly it worked.

Here is repository link.
github.com/hakankaan/movie

Comment: without looking your repo. Is `truncate` inside flexbox? I assume `h-2` `p-2` work as expected

Comment: No, truncate is not in a flex. h-2 p-2 given to the img tag and this img tag has a flex parent.

Comment: strange behaviour. I tested your repo, h-2, p-2, truncate can be applied to p tag without problem. Have you tried to remove the node_modules & lock file and reinstall it again?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. A repo link isn't adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing node_modules and lock file and reinstalling it fixed my problem.