# Many Tailwind CSS classes doesn´t work on my Angular 12 project

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

I am developing an Angular 12 project with Tailwind CSS installed. I have followed the [official docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular) and it seems everything works; but I can´t understand why some classes work and others not.

For example, I can have this piece of code, trying to add two Tailwind classes on my div:

```
<div class="text-center mt-2">

    <h2>Please go back to <a class="custom-links" href="./login">login</a></h2>
</div>
```

And the text-center class works, but the mt-2 doesn´t. This kind of things is happening on the whole project. The way I had to solve it is using traditional CSS or mixing it with Tailwind, like this:

```
<div id="back-to-login" class="text-center">

    <h2>Please go back to <a class="custom-links" href="./login">login</a></h2>
</div>
```

And on the css:

```
#back-to-login{
    
    margin-top: 40px;

}
```

Then it works fine and the margin-top is applied.

Do you know what could be happening?

Reinstalling node_modules like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67499193/tailwind-css-classes-on-some-components-dont-work) doesn´t solve it.

Thanks a lot.

I add the code of the styles.css and tailwind.config

styles.css

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@font-face {
  font-family: "firechat";
  src: url(./assets/fonts/blazed/Blazed.ttf);
}

/*
  to change the default h1 styles on tailwind

  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#extending-preflight

*/
@layer base {
  h1 {
    @apply text-6xl;
  }
}

/*tailwind and own styles*/

#firechat-font{
  font-family: "firechat";
  color:red;
}

.custom-links{
  color:red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Tailwind config file:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

EDIT: What I am seeing now is that for example mt-2 applies and appear on devTools (maybe problem was it was to small change to notice, my fault), but a bigger margin like mt-4 or mt-6 doesn´t. It happened also with other properties.

Comment: Share style.scss where you have added tailwind and tailwind config file

Comment: @zainhassan thanks, it is done. It is not added in any scss file, but on the global style.css for the project.

Comment: can you see `mt-2` is applied to your div in devTools?

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov I edited main post. What I am seeing now is that for example mt-2 applies and appear on devTools (maybe problem was it was to small change to notice, my fault), but a bigger margin like mt-4 or mt-6 doesn´t. It happened also with other properties.

Comment: This is strange but it seems that you've installed the latest version of tailwind with angular12 maybe something is wrong with it? Is it possible to install tailwind v2 and quickly check if it works.

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov you got it :) I will answer the question or I can delete it and you can answer if you want to get the point because you gave the solution.

Comment: @FranP posted my answer. So happy it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you've installed the latest version of tailwind with angular 12 maybe something is wrong with it? Try install tailwind v2 and see if it works. Some breaking changes could happen since tailwind v3

Comment: Also, as @penleychan added, it is a good idea to upgrade angular, then it will work better with Tailwind v3

Answer (score 27):

For some reason, in my **styles.scss**, I had to import the variables as follows

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

instead of

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

reload and it worked. Angular version 14.1.0, Tailwindcss version 3.1.7

Comment: Any idea why though ?

Comment: @Shrihari. It's the same way you'd reference the package name for bulma / bootstrap / material for sass files. That's why Angular introduced the shortened imports in scss files.

Comment: Oh yeah totally forgot. Thanks ! Checked my other projects, I was using @import .

Answer (score 10):

Angular 14
Try **tailwind.config.js** like this

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
  module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,ts}', './projects/**/*.{html,ts}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
 }
```

Comment: You add the answer and saved me from searching elsewhere. I have a `projects` structure. The normal tailwind configuration didn't have that. A good thing you put it here. Even if one has a different approach it is worth it to leave a solution than may help someone later. Thank you.

Comment: Well done boy, good find.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MaksatRahmanov I found the solution. It seems the problem was I installed the latest Tailwind version (v3) with Angular 12. I switched back to v2 and everything works fine.

The only problem with it is that many things have changed between both versions ([check here](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3)), so it could break many things working properly with v3.

Comment: While going to v2 works, you will be using JIT (if you are using it) as experimental stage since and probably have to set TAILWIND_MODE=watch, v3 is when it was release officially. JIT is on by default on v3 this was an known issue, it was fixed in angular@13.2 and tailwind@3.0.17. I would suggest to upgrade to angular if you can.

Comment: @penleychan yeah, you are right, upgrading angular worked and now it seems the things didn´t worked (like `mt-6`) work now with v3  :) Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tutorial: https://medium.com/tunaiku-tech/angular-11-tailwindcss-2-0-blazing-fast-cfa20ae3a5e9. In that tutorial, TailwindCSS version 2 is used. If you want TailwindCSS version 3, then kindly change the configuration file to match the TailwindCSS version 3 config file. By setting up the angular project as mentioned in the above tutorial TailwindCSS version 3 is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me. I checked my tailwind.config.js many times, and

```
content: [    
"../src/**/*.html"
]
```

...should be enough.But for some reason unknown to me, it just doesn't rebuild on adding new classes. So, same as you, I didn't see new classes in built CSS files. I almost gave up, but in the end here is my workaround:

src/tailwind.scss:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

New script in package.json, called "tailwind" - it watches for changes in your HTML and rebuilds your css.

postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
    }
}
```

Also installed npm-run-all, so I can on "npm run start" serve and watch tailwind for changes:

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "nx",
"serve": "ng serve --configuration=dev",
"start": "npm-run-all --parallel serve tailwind",    
"tailwind": "npx tailwindcss --postcss -i ./src/tailwind.scss -o ./src/app/scss/tailwind.css --watch"
 }
```

angular.json:

```
"styles": [
            "src/app/scss/tailwind.css"
          ]
```

And there you go. You will serve and rebuild CSS whenever new classes are added to your HTML files. I know it's a workaround, but at least it works 100%.

Answer (score 1):

I spent long time with this issue, finally founded
stop your running app and run again: ng serve
then tailwind will applied properly, as documentation of tailwindcss

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too, when generating new Angular project the global style.scss will contain `/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */` 
make sure to add `@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;` above this comment otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score -1):

> The solution is quite simple. Just set `important: true` in **tailwind.confing.js** which will treat all the utilities as higher precedence.

check out at [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important)

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
  important: true
}
```