# Some Tailwind CSS classes sometimes don't work in react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm very new to Tailwind, and I have weird problem. When I apply tailwind classes to react component, some of them (eg. bg-default-800, rounded-lg) work normal, but some don't.

```
export function Tile(props: PropsWithChildren<propsInterface>) {
    return (
        <div
            className={'bg-default-800 m-2 rounded-lg flex flex-col justify-center ' +
                'w-' + props.width + '/4 h-' + props.height + ' '}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here's usage of this component:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className={'flex flex-row flex-wrap'}>
        <Tile width={1} height={36}>
            tile 1
        </Tile>
        <Tile width={3} height={36}>
            tile 2
        </Tile>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here's tailwind.config.cjs:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'default': {
          '800': '#166534',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

In this case, 'w-1/4' works, but 'w-3/4' don't. It worked only after I had changed className to hardcoded values (without props). Then, I redo changes and it still works, which is weird. When it comes to height, 'h-32' works, but 'h-36' doesn't, like many other values from tailwind documentation. Shift + F5 doesn't help.

Comment: Did you have a look to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67499193/tailwind-css-classes-on-some-components-dont-work?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `mode: 'jit'` option in tailwind config.

Tailwind is trying to remove all non used classes from the final bundle.

From the docs:

> Dynamic values Note that you still need to write purgeable HTML when
> using arbitrary values, and your classes need to exist as complete
> strings for Tailwind to detect them correctly.
>
> Don't use string concatenation to create class names

```
<div className={`mt-[${size === 'lg' ? '22px' : '17px' }]`}></div>
```

> Do dynamically select a complete class name

```
<div className={ size === 'lg' ? 'mt-[22px]' : 'mt-[17px]' }></div>
```

In your example you are using the first version, which won't work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [default config](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/stubs/defaultConfig.stub.js) of tailwinds